# AWS SAM fails to build layer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-sam

I have read that SAM now supports building layers and followed the directions mentioned [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/releases/tag/v0.50.0). However, i am getting a build error when i try to build the layer locally with `sam build samDeployLayer`

```
Build Failed
Error: NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmPack - NPM Failed: npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "E:\Development\sam-deploy\src\sam-deploy-layer" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Here is my template file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  sam-deploy
Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  samDeploy:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/sam-deploy
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Description: A Lambda function that returns a static string.
      FunctionName: "sam-deploy"
      Layers:
        - !Ref samDeployLayer
      Policies:
        # Give Lambda basic execution Permission to the helloFromLambda
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
  samDeployLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: sam-deploy-layer
      ContentUri: src/sam-deploy-layer
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs12.x
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: nodejs12.x
```

I have included both the `CompatibleRuntimes` and `Metadata` properties as per the requirement to build layers. `package.json` for this layer is located at `src/sam-deploy-layer/nodejs` as required for nodeJS runtimes and i am using SAM CLI version 0.53.0. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should have a package.json for BOTH node projects (samDeploy & samDeployLayer).  This file should be located in `src/sam-deploy` and `src/sam-deploy-layer` location (respectively) Otherwise update your `CodeUri` and/or `ContentUri`values.

Answer (score 1):

Place `package.json` under `src/sam-deploy-layer/`.
After running `sam build`, the directory `.aws-sam/build/samDeployLayer/nodejs/node_modules/` should be created.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a folder named nodejs in src/sam-deploy-layer. Here, you can do npm init and npm install (packages in your layer).